# How to get these powershell regex matches output onto the same lines

Tags: regex, powershell

The data being pulled from this.

```
<IPv4 id="id456F07894780" name="XYZ" comment="stuf123" ro="False"      address="1.1.1.1" netmask="255.255.255.255"/>
```

Here is my PS script.

```
$input_path = ‘c:\ps\search\fwbuilder.txt’
$output_file = ‘c:\ps\extracted_ip_addresses.txt’
$regex = '((?<=\bname="\b).*?(?=\".comment\b)|(?is)(?<=\baddress="\b).*?(?=\".netmask\b))'
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

I want the display to be like this.

XYZ 1.1.1.1

But instead it is showing up as

XYZ

1.1.1.1
EDIT*************

I was able to accomplish what I needed using the XML parser in PS.

Get-Content -Path C:\ps\search\network.xml | Select-Xml -XPath    //Network |     Select-object -ExpandProperty "node" | Select-object      "name","address","netmask","id"

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Not that it can't be done using regex but you might be complicating things to much. *([and regex really isn't the right tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/52598])*

If your input is valid xml, I would use following approach

```
[xml]'<IPv4 id="id456F07894780" name="XYZ" comment="stuf123" ro="False" address="1.1.1.1" netmask="255.255.255.255"/>' | 
ForEach-Object {"$($_.IPv4.name) $($_.IPv4.address)"}
```

**Output**

```
XYZ 1.1.1.1
```

Applied to your files, following might be all that's needed

```
[xml](Get-Content c:\ps\search\fwbuilder.txt) | ForEach-Object {
    "$($_.IPv4.name) $($_.IPv4.address)" 
} | Out-File c:\ps\extracted_ip_addresses.txt
```

**Edit**

as per your comments, the txt file doesn't contain a root element, you might add one on the fly as follows

```
([xml]"<root>$(Get-Content c:\ps\search\fwbuilder.txt)</root>").root.IPv4 | ForEach-Object { 
    "$($_.name) $($_.address)" 
}
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I did go down the XML route and wasn't able to get any luck. I tried your example and it.
    Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid 
child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."

Comment: @AlexHuthmacher - I assume you are talking about the `get-content` example?! First thing that comes to mind is that fwbuilder.txt doesn't contain valid xml. Can you post a minimal content of the file that still returns that exception?

Comment: So I think it is because there are multiple lines in the file. When I just have one line it works, but if I add another line it fails.
<IPv4 id="id456F07894780" name="XYZ" comment="stuf123" ro="False" address="1.1.1.1" netmask="255.255.255.255"/>
works

but
<IPv4 id="id456F07894780" name="XYZ" comment="stuf123" ro="False" address="1.1.1.1" netmask="255.255.255.255"/>
<IPv4 id="id456F07894780" name="XYZ" comment="stuf123" ro="False" address="1.1.1.1" netmask="255.255.255.255"/>

does not.

Comment: You'd have to add a root element. I'll adjust my example.

Comment: It turns out all I had to do was this.    
Get-Content -Path C:\ps\search\Ipv4.xml | Select-Xml -XPath //IPv4 | Select-object -ExpandProperty "node" | Select-object "name","address","netmask","comment"

Comment: @AlexHuthmacher - You can post your solution and accept it as answered. Others might benefit from it.